# Show array values in textview in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an array named bookmark,it contains values,i displayed it in a tableview cell,i know how to display it in tablecell.but i want the same array to display it in textview.this is my code for tableview.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
 }
```

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return [bookmarks count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        UIImageView* img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgCELL3@2X-1"]];
        [cell setBackgroundView:img];
        [img release];
    }
    cell.textLabel.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:15];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@:%@ ",[[bookmarks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"book"],[[bookmarks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"chapter"],[[bookmarks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"verse"],[[bookmarks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"text"]];
    // Set up the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

i want to replace cell.textlabel.text with mytextview.text = ?.Please help me to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is ur textView actually? Do u want to add a textView to ur cell or u have a textView already somewhere else and just want to show this text there?

Comment: Do you want to display it in one single `UITextView`?

Comment: @Nekto yes i want to display it in a single textview.

Comment: @ElanthiraiyanS my text view is not in uitableview,its a diffrent view outside the tableview.i want to write the mytextview.text =?in viewdidload method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set text of your `UITextView` in the same manner as text of `UILabel`

```
 mytextview.text = [[bookmarks objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"text"];
```

Or, for example, in loop:

```
NSString *resultStr = @"";
for (id bookmark in bookmarks)
{
     resultStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@. %@", resultStr, [bookmark objectForKey:@"text"]]];
}
mytextview.text = resultStr;
```